# jQuery $.when().done() not working as expected with JSONP when loading a local .json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm building an SPA using Sammy and Knockout powered by a REST Web Service available on a different URL.

I'm noticing some odd behavior when returning JSONP versus JSON when using `$.when().done()`...

`.done()` never fires, but `.fail()` will, even though the status code I receive is 200, and JSONP Linter tells me that my JSONP is valid:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $.when($.getJSON('endpoint1?callback=?', null),
            $,getJSON('endpoint2?callback=?', null))
        .done(function(resp1, resp2) {
                console.log(resp1); // this is never called
            });
        })
        .fail(function(obj) {
            console.log(obj); // this is called, but why?
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

A sample response returned is:

```
callback({
    "external-links": [
        {
            "nav_link_text": "Stack Overflow",
            "url": "http://stackoverflow.com"
        }
    ]
});
```

If I return JSON instead of JSONP, `.done()` works as expected. What am I doing wrong or need to change?

Comment: If it works with JSON, then why not use that?  Are these cross-domain calls?  If they are on the same domain, just use JSON and call it a day.

Comment: Right now, I'm just developing locally, so I *can* switch them over to JSON, but I would like to avoid surprises. In production, these will be cross-domain calls.

Comment: What do you see in the console from the `.fail` function?

Comment: @RocketHazmat If I pass in the response object returned by `.fail()` I can see the responseText (see above example), a statusCode of 200 and ready state of 4.

Comment: Is this behavior a side-effect of JSONP requests not leveraging an XMLHTTPRequest object?

Comment: `$.when`/`.done()` works fine with JSONP requests.  http://jsfiddle.net/8PqFq/1/

Comment: Hmm. That certainly does work. Guess I'll need to keep experimenting.

Comment: The `.fail` callback is passed multiple parameters, have a look at each of them, not just the 1st.  `.fail(function(){ console.log(arguments); })`

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere: ReferenceError: callback is not defined

Comment: How are you making your JSONP requests?  You want `?callback=?` at the end of your URL, *don't* put a value there, jQuery will set replace the `?` for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40278/discussion-between-brandon-and-rocket-hazmat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is specified here:

> ReferenceError: callback is not defined

Your JSONP response has `callback` hard-coded.  That's incorrect.  JSONP needs to set the function name dynamically.

When jQuery sends a JSONP request, it creates a function called `jQuery123456` (or something like that) and sends that name in the request.  It calls `endpoint1?callback=jQuery123456`.  The job of JSONP is to make a call to *that* function.  Your JSONP needs to return:

```
jQuery123456({
    your: 'data'
})
```

You need to use the value of the `callback` parameter.

---

If for some reason, creating the JSONP "dynamically" isn't an option, you can force jQuery to name the callback function it creates.  You need to use `$.ajax` for this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'endpoint1',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: false, // Don't add the "?callback=?" param,
                  // you're not using it anyway
    jsonpCallback: 'callback' // Force jQuery to use "callback"
                              // as the function name
});
```

Note: jQuery probably won't like having the same callback value for multiple requests.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help. Because I'm loading a static .json file from the local filesystem in development, I can't get the `callback` parameter from the querystring to set it as part of the response. So, I just added a different `jsonpCallback` parameter for each file returned until I have a staging server in place.

Comment: @Brandon: Ah!  Didn't realize they were static files.  In that case, yeah, just set a different callback in each one, and update the `jsonpCallback` value accordingly :-)

Comment: Sorry, that's completely my fault. I really need to get more than 3 hours sleep when working on complicated JavaScript apps.

Comment: @Brandon: Pffft, who needs sleep?  That's what coffee is for!

Comment: Haha. Luckily my wife bought me Dunkin' Turbo for just these types of occasions :)